# How can I find all the data from a array of Ids in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, server

When I am going to insert multiple data into database. I want to check is data already exist into the database or not.

But I can't find multiple result with following code.

```
await Wishlist.find({ user: req.user.id, product:{ $in: ids } });
```

Kindly please help me

Comment: Can you share your database schema? What's the type of the `product`  field?

Comment: And what do you mean when you say that you can't find multiple results?  Are you getting an error, no results, something else? What are the values of `req.user.id` and `ids`? What are some sample documents?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$elemMatch`. Please research about [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

```
await Wishlist.findOne({
            user: req.user.id,
            product: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    _id: ids
                }
            }
        });
```